# How to install latest Kodi on latest Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, compiling, kodi

The current version of Kodi in Debian10's repositories is v17.6. This version didn't work properly (it wasn't usable). Hence I'm trying to install the latest version.

I followed the steps of [the "Debian/Ubuntu build guide" of the Kodi repository](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/docs/README.Ubuntu.md) except that I didn't add the PPA. I used `sudo apt build-dep kodi` as packages "flatbuffers-dev" and "libshairplay-dev" could not be found and there wasn't an installation candidate for "libmysqlclient-dev" when trying to build dependencies manually. When trying to follow the steps of "Build Kodi" of the "Linux build guide" which are the last step of the "Debian/Ubuntu build guide" I get these errors when running command `cmake ../kodi -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DX11_RENDER_SYSTEM=gl`:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:95 (core_add_library):   Unknown CMake
>   command "core_add_library".
>
> CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:   No cmake_minimum_required
>   command is present.  A line of code such as
>
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
>
> should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may
>   be lower   if you wish to support older CMake versions for this
>   project.  For more   information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
>   This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Do I need to add the PPA and should I? Or is there something else that should be done to compile it? Would it be recommended to install it via [the flatpak](https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/tv.kodi.Kodi) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **The latest version is in Debian bullseye now so the below isn't needed anymore**. If you're running Debian 11, just run `sudo apt-get install kodi`.
- *The latest version is in Debian buster-backports now so the below isn't needed anymore*. If you're running Debian 10, just run `sudo apt install -t buster-backports kodi`.
- [There's a new (currently unofficial) repository for the latest Kodi under Debian](https://basilgello.github.io/kodi-nightly-debian-repo)
- [There's a new build guide now which works with Debian 10 when running a few additional commands.](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/issues/18612) This worked for me:

  - Run `sudo apt-get install rapidjson-dev`
  - Follow [this guide](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/docs/README.Linux.md) (you can ignore step "Enable internal dependencies")
  - Run `sha256sum ~/Downloads/19.0a2-Matrix.zip` (or whatever the file downloaded from *GitHub* is named)
  - Before running the build command (or after getting error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunistring") run `sudo apt-get install libunistring-dev`

Comment: This answer would be nicely enhanced by including not only a simple link, but those extra commands that are required.

Comment: I don't know if others might require some other packages from the huge list of dependencies in the link or whether `sudo apt build-dep kodi` (with deb-src enabled in sources.list) would also work for versions newer than 18.8. I updated the solution.